# How to remove a duplicate entry in exception handling in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, logging

I am trying to implement the following behavior of `logger`: if there is an (outer) exception - try to read a file `123`. If you fail - throw inner exception.
If I write code as shown below

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', filemode='a', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")


def my_div(a, b):
    try:
        return a/b
    except Exception as e:  # outer exception
        try:
            with open('123', 'rb') as fi: 
                pass
        except Exception as e1: # inner exception
            logger.exception(f"inner error\n{storage}")
        logger.exception(f"outer error\n{storage}")


storage = {}
for i in [1,0]:
    storage[i] = my_div(2, i)
```

I get a duplicate for the outer exception.

```
ERROR:my_logger:inner error
{1: 2.0}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/workspace/acne/src/scratch/logger_related/minimal_logger.py", line 9, in my_div
    return a/b
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/workspace/acne/src/scratch/logger_related/minimal_logger.py", line 12, in my_div
    with open('123', 'rb') as fi:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '123'
ERROR:my_logger:outer error
{1: 2.0}
Traceback (most recent call last):    # How to remove this duplicate?
  File "D:/workspace/acne/src/scratch/logger_related/minimal_logger.py", line 9, in my_div
    return a/b
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

How can I remove the duplicate (line with `# How to remove this duplicate?`)?

---

Update. The desired behavior: if file wasn't found, There should not be a duplicate line. If it was found, then only `outer error` is logged.

Comment: This is what's supposed to happen. The inner error `e1` is caused by `e`, hence included in the traceback, then you _also_ log `e` directly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, what is the correct way to avoid duplication?

Comment: Well one option would be to log the outer error only in [`else`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#else-clause).